# Select statement order by child and name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is the result I need

[image: what i have]

This is the result I have

[image]

This is my query

```
select a.id, a.name, a.parent 
from categ a left join categ b on a.parent=b.id 
order by coalesce(b.name, a.name), a.name
```

This is my database http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f059f4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to sort by:

1. Parent name
2. Child name

And you want the parent to sort above the children.

Therefore you need to add a third column to the `ORDER BY` clause in order to discriminate between the child and the parents.

This should work for your specific case:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.parent 
from categ a left join categ b on a.parent=b.id 
order by coalesce(b.name, a.name), (b.id is not null), a.name
```